# Strange character in textoutput when piping from tasklist command WIN7

Tags: windows-7, cmd, piping, tasklist

Strange character 'ÿ' in textoutput (should have been a space). Why is this, how can I fix it? Does not happen when command is executed at prompt. Only when piped to textfile.

Windows 7

c:\tasklist > text.txt

outputs:

System                           4 Services                   0      1ÿ508 K

smss.exe                       312 Services                   0      1ÿ384 K

csrss.exe                      492 Services                   0      5ÿ052 K

Answer (score 1):

The "space" you could see in the console window was not the standard space character with the ASCII code of 32 (0x20), but the non-breaking space with the ASCII code of 255 (0xFF) in probably most OEM code pages.

After redirecting the output to a file, you likely opened the file in an editor that by default used a different code page to display the contents, possibly Windows-1252 since the character with the code of 255 is `ÿ` in Windows-1252.

Answer (score 1):

Andriy was right.

I added

```
chcp 1252
```

at the begin of my batch file, and all weird characters were correctly translated into spaces in the output file.